# Android retrofit response return internal server error while downloading files from server

Tags: java, php, android, laravel

I'm working on an Android project, the app need to download PDF file that is generated from the web. I'm using Laravel and DOMPdf to generate the pdf file (laravel dependency). I want to download the file to to the android with retrofit, but when i log the response it says:

> onResponse: Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=500, message=Internal Server 
>   Error, url=http://10.0.2.2/warehouse-api/public/api/get-stock-out}

When i try it on chrome / postman, it works and it will download the generated pdf file.

I want to know what's happening in here.

Here is my code:

## ReportFragment.java

```java
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock_out_report, container, false);
        generateBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_generate_stockout);
        service = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofit().create(ReportService.class);
        generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked");
              if(checkPermission()){
                    call = service.getStockOutReport();
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                            final String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() /1000L+".pdf";
                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                        try{
                                            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                            File file = new File(path+File.separator+"stock-out"+File.separator,filename);
                                            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                            IOUtils.write(response.body().bytes(), fileOutputStream);
                                        }catch (IOException e){
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Erorr While Writing Files");
                                            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                                        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }.execute();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse2: " +response);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse3: " +response);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

## ReportService.java

```java
@GET("get-stock-out")
@Streaming
Call<ResponseBody> getStockOutReport();
```

## ReportController.php

```php
public function getWeeklyStockOutReport()
{
       $stockOuts = StockOut::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('stock-out', compact('stockOuts'));
        return $pdf->download(Carbon::now().'-'.'stock-out.pdf');
 }
```

i'm expecting the android app to be able to download the .pdf file

Thankyou!